# How to align text through text-* classes on Twitter Bootstrap Button Group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to align left the text of the `button`s on a Twitter Bootstrap Button Group using class `text-left`.

But, when I put the class in `a` or `div` tags (as the first class or the last class) the alignment doesn't change and is always center.

The left align works only if I put a `style="text-align: left;` on the `a` tag.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-lg" role="group">
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" role="button" href="page1.html">Short Text</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" role="button" href="page2.html">Long link text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because bootstrap's CSS as by default `text-align:center` on `.btn` class, so by inserting the `text-left` class on the same element, won't affect due to having the same specificity.

Create a custom CSS for that.

```css
.btn-group-lg .btn {
  text-align: left
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-lg" role="group">
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" role="button" href="page1.html">Short Text</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" role="button" href="page2.html">Long link text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, works with the new class. But, why `text-left` when appended to the classes on the `a` tag don't override the `text-align` attribute from `btn` class?